# Request removal of a Google+ page when all other ways of accessing it fail

Tags: google-plus

My friend has forgotten her Google+ email address and wants to delete her Google+ account. She can't access it any more, none of the account troubleshooting steps help, what can she do? There is a picture of her on there and some information that she wants to make private or remove.

She doesn't have a mobile phone associated with the account and none of the special question options are there any more.

I've checked some of the existing solutions on this site to this problem but they all talk about using the account access troubleshooting steps, which she has already tried. The problem is not that she wants to access the account, it's that she wants to delete the account, and it seems the only way to do that is to login to it and then delete it. She wants to delete it because there is a picture of her on there and there is a review attached to the profile that advertises a business. Her picture is being used as an advertisement. She does not want this or give her consent for it to happen.

I'm aware that Google allows people to remove information about themselves from the Internet. Is that an avenue that she might pursue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend was able to have the page removed by filling in the following form:

[Report Impersonation - Report a profile impersonating you](https://support.google.com/plus/troubleshooter/1715140?hl=en-GB#ts=1715142)

She had to provide a photo of her ID and explain the situation, I don't know what she wrote on there, she tells me that they contacted her telling her that they had decided to remove the page.

I checked it myself, and it is no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

The big problem here is that she needs to prove that it's her account. If it were easy to get an account removed just by saying "no, really, that's me; I just can't prove it", can you imagine the chaos that would cause? The European "right to be forgotten" doesn't apply here, I don't think, and she'd need to be in the EU in any event. Since she wants a photo taken down, a DMCA takedown request *might* be the avenue to pursue, but even then I think that's dicey.

Comment: She is willing to prove who she is but it isn't clear how to do that if you can't remember your email address and you don't have a mobile associated with your account, previously there were some secret questions you could answer but they are gone. it's definately her in the picture and you could see that straight away if there was some way to upload a photo of her id card. she lives in the eu if that helps. we looked at the google site and there doesn't seem to be a phone number to call where you can just talk to someone and explain the situation. there doesn't seem to be a form to fill out ei

Comment: Generally speaking, you're not going to get telephone support for a service that you don't pay for, especially one as big as what Google is offering. Posting on the Google+ Product Forums might help, since there are a few Google employees who trawl through there once in a while.